# woocommerce axios react

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I don't understand why my request to WooCommerce API doesn't work.
My usage on react App via axios:

First try:

```
return axios.get( 'http://domain/wp-json/wc/v3/products?featured=true',
  {
      headers: {
        'consumer_key': 'ck_xxx',
        'consumer_secret': 'cs_xxx',
        'key_id': 111,
        'key_permissions': 'read_write',
        'user_id': 111,
  }
)
```

Second one:

```
return axios( {
  url: 'http://domain/wp-json/wc/v3/products?featured=true',
    headers: {
      'origin': 'http;//localhost:3000',
      'consumer_key': 'ck_x',
      'consumer_secret': 'cs_x',
      'key_id': 111,
      'key_permissions': 'read_write',
      'user_id': 111,
      },
      method: 'GET',
    }
} )
```

And I get CORS error. But using Insomnia software I create a GET request to `http://domain/wp-json/wc/v3/products?featured=true` with Basic Auth tab:

```
USERNAME ck_x
PASSWORD cs_x
```

therefore response status is 200 OK.

I appreciate to understand what I'm doing wrong in axios inside my React App.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same problem. Using Postman I managed to get a 200 response if I set it to Oauth 1.0 and input consumer_key and consumer_secret. Woocommerce documentation says to use Basic Authentication but that results in a 401 error.

Comment: I didn't... and I'm not using WordPress in current projects so I didn't get deeper in search about this. I'd try `fetch` (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) native in JS instead `axios`, maybe it works

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks tho.

Comment: Post as answer and let people know how to solve it :)

Comment: $20 bucks... just kidding, I'll post it when i get back to the computer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue with Woocommerce Oauth 1.0 authentication and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45465247/2550766) worked for me. I'm running it on localhost, so far so good.

**Edit:**

Let me elaborate this answer a bit more. I just started learning React last night and the best way to learn is by doing. I'll explain as a newbie for a newbie. Here we go...

I created this *Woocommerce helper object* that can be called from any component and it does all the hard work for you:

**`Woocommerce.js`**

```
import axios from "axios";
import Oauth from "oauth-1.0a";
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";
import jQuery from "jquery";

const ck = "ck_...";
const cs = "cs_...";
const baseURL = "http://yourdomain.com/wp-json";

const Woocommerce = {
  getProducts: () => {
    return makeRequest("/wc/v3/products");
  },
  getProductByID: id => {
    return makeRequest("/wc/v3/products/" + id);
  }
};

function makeRequest(endpoint, method = "GET") {
  const oauth = getOauth();

  const requestData = {
    url: baseURL + endpoint,
    method
  };

  const requestHTTP =
    requestData.url + "?" + jQuery.param(oauth.authorize(requestData));

  return axios.get(requestHTTP);
}

function getOauth() {
  return Oauth({
    consumer: {
      key: ck,
      secret: cs
    },
    signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
    hash_function: function(base_string, key) {
      return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(base_string, key));
    }
  });
}

export default Woocommerce;
```

You will need to install all the necessary packages by running the commands:

```
npm install axios jquery crypto-js
npm install oauth-1.0a --production
```

**How to use it**

First import it to the component:

```
import Woocommerce from "./functions/Woocommerce";
```

Then from inside the component you can call it like this to get all the products:

```
// All products (array of objects)
state = { products: [], isLoaded: false };

componentWillMount() {
  Woocommerce.getProducts().then(res =>
    this.setState({ products: res.data, isLoaded: true })
  );
}
```

Or, to get only one product by ID, you can do:

```
// Single product (object)
state = { product: {}, isLoaded: false };

componentWillMount() {
  Woocommerce.getProductByID(123).then(res =>
    this.setState({ product: res.data, isLoaded: true })
  );
}
```

As you can probably see, you can elaborate more functions inside of the Woocommerce helper and retrieve products using the Woocommerce REST API as you wish.

Happy coding... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @ColdTuna!

Just in case anyone wants a sample code with React Hooks:

**Products.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Woocommerce from "../functions/Woocommerce";


function Products() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(0);
    
  useEffect(() => {
        Woocommerce.getProducts()
            .then( (res) => {
                setProducts(res.data)
            } );     
        },[]
    );

  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.values(products).map( (item, itemIndex) => {
          return <li key={item.id}>{itemIndex}-{item.name},{item.price} - 
                    {
                      item.images.map( (image, imgIndex) => {
                        return <img key={imgIndex} src={image.src}></img>;
                      })
                    }   
                </li>
      })
      }
    </ul>
  );
}
  
export default Products
```

Comment: Nice example. The `<li key={index}>` would be replaced by `<li key={item.id}>` as possible (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: In above code `<img key={index} ...` make use of the same variable name, maybe errors happen. Maybe `itemIndex` and `imgIndex` would be good names, I think so

Comment: Thanks @EnriqueRené. I will edit the code as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It's old question but maybe it works for who struggle with this problem. You can use woocommerce 's own api (https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)

```
// Install:
// npm install --save @woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api

// Setup:
const WooCommerceRestApi = require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-    api").default;
// import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api"; //     Supports ESM

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceRestApi({
   url: 'http://example.com', // Your store URL
   consumerKey: 'consumer_key', // Your consumer key
   consumerSecret: 'consumer_secret', // Your consumer secret
   version: 'wc/v3' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
});
```